# date command --iso-8601 option

Tags: date

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164773/89609) and comments mention `--rfc-3339` and a "hidden" `--iso-8601` option that I have used for a long time and now seems to be undocumented.

When did that option documentation get removed from the `--help` text?

Will the option go away anytime soon?

Comment: To get this feature on OSX I finally got the GNU tools: $ brew install coreutils ; gdate --iso-8601 -d "yesterday 12:00"

Comment: @AnneTheAgile for macOS, you can manually format the date like so: "date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"

Comment: I feel like the top answers are pretty complicated considering that `date -Iseconds` seems to "just work" on all platforms

Comment: in 2023 `date -I` is working at UBUNTU

Answer (score 162, accepted):

The option was introduced in the coreutils `date` (which is probably what you have) in 1999 (Apr. 8).

The documentation was removed in [2005](http://git.sv.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=2c29ba03) without much explanation in the commit.

In [2011](http://git.sv.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=2f1384b7), the help for --iso-8601 was reintroduced with the following explanation:

```
We deprecated and undocumented the --iso-8601 (-I) option mostly
because date could not parse that particular format.  Now that
it can, it's time to restore the documentation.
* src/date.c (usage): Document it.
* doc/coreutils.texi (Options for date): Reinstate documentation.
Reported by Hubert Depesz Lubaczewski in http://bugs.gnu.org/7444.
```

It looks like the help was taken out in version 5.90 and put back in, in version 8.15 (it is not in my 8.13) and the comment above suggests that it is now back to stay and not likely to be disappearing any time soon.

In version 8.31 (as provided by Solus July 2020) the man page has these two options:

```
   -I[FMT], --iso-8601[=FMT]
          output date/time in ISO 8601 format.  FMT='date' for date only (the default), 'hours', 'minutes', 'sec‐
          onds', or 'ns' for date and time to the indicated precision.  Example: 2006-08-14T02:34:56-06:00

   --rfc-3339=FMT
          output date/time in RFC 3339 format.  FMT='date', 'seconds', or 'ns' for date and time to the indicated
          precision.  Example: 2006-08-14 02:34:56-06:00
```

Answer (score 149):

**For a platform independent, (almost) fully compliant,** [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) **date,
use this:**

```
date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
```

This will result in a time such as: `2021-01-16T23:09:44-0500`

This should work on macOS (BSD) and Linux.

**Technically, for ***full*** compliance, it should be:**

```
date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"
```

*Note the offset (time zone) field
contains a colon '`:`' **between** the '`%`' and the '`z`'.* 
This will result in a **fully** complaint ISO 8601 time such as: `2021-01-16T23:09:44-05:00`

But this ***doesn't*** work on macOS (as of this writing).
This should work on Linux (i.e., with GNU `date`).

**For [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time (zero offset, historically known as "Zulu time")
you can use (note the `-u`, to get UTC time,
and note that the '`Z`' is *not* preceded by a '`%`' (or a colon)
– it is a literal '`Z`'):**

```
date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
```

This will result in a time such as: `2021-01-17T04:16:14Z`

Comment: Mac OSX seems happy now w/zsh & bash: `% date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"` yields `2022-03-22T11:05:42:z` on `Darwin 21.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.3.0`.

Comment: @jgreve no, you just showed that Mac's `date` does not understand the `%:z` format control. Check your output thoroughly, it wrote literal `:z` instead of your time zone with the `:` separator like for example `date +%:z` -> `+02:00` --- Also shell normally has nothing to do with this because `date` is normally an external executable, not the shell's built-in.

Comment: argh. :-/  I stand corrected.

Comment: MacOS 12.6 supports `date -Iseconds`, can't figure out when this was changed though!

Comment: The first example also is not fully portable, as `%z` is not defined (only `%Z` is defined) in the POSIX standard for `date(1)` (see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html)

Answer (score 63):

The --help got an update recently actually, so the option definitely isn't going away:

```
-I[FMT], --iso-8601[=FMT]  output date/time in ISO 8601 format.
                             FMT='date' for date only (the default),
                             'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds', or 'ns'
                             for date and time to the indicated precision.
                             Example: 2006-08-14T02:34:56-06:00

     -R, --rfc-2822        output date and time in RFC 2822 format.
                             Example: Mon, 14 Aug 2006 02:34:56 -0600

         --rfc-3339=FMT    output date/time in RFC 3339 format.
                             FMT='date', 'seconds', or 'ns'
                             for date and time to the indicated precision.
                             Example: 2006-08-14 02:34:56-06:00
```

Note since coreutils-8.27 `--rfc-2822` is deprecated in favor of the more general `--rfc-email`

```
     -R, --rfc-email       output date and time in RFC 5322 format.
                             Example: Mon, 14 Aug 2006 02:34:56 -0600
```

Comment: It would be nice if there was a `-I` style without the timezone. Would be more useful for logging, etc, where the timezone doesn't matter

Comment: @naught101 you can get rid of the timezone offset by specifying the component parts: `date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`.

Answer (score 57):

I'm running Linux Mint and the option is available:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Release:    17.3
Codename:   rosa
```

The execution of the command:

```
$ date --iso-8601=seconds
2016-12-14T09:53:25-0400
```

Comment: or just `date -Iseconds`

Comment: but it doesn't appends `Z` to the end so this is not fully complete ISO timestamp

Comment: That's the closest I could get with available parameters

Comment: `date -In` (same as `date -Ins`) or `date -Is` same as (`date -Iseconds`) etc.

Comment: "but it doesn't appends Z to the end so this is not fully complete ISO timestamp" Z is the UTC timezone. `+00:00` is the same as `Z`. `+00:00Z` is not correct.

Comment: For a filename compatible format, I use `$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ")`

Answer (score 3):

## I think this is perfect, maybe you will also like it:

```bash
date -u --iso-8601=ns | sed s/+00:00/Z/ | sed s/,/./
```

Result example: `2022-12-10T20:44:36.753578818Z`