# Get current date and time in standard ISO 8601 format on console in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, date, bsd, date-utility

I would like to get the current date-time conveniently on the console in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ

For example: `2019-07-13T01:09:35Z`

I know the `date` command displays the current date-time, but not in ISO 8601 format by default. The `-I` option shows the date-only portion in standard format. And `-Iseconds` displays `2019-07-13T01:18:10+00:00`. That is close, but:

- I would prefer the usual `Z` on the end for an offset of zero, rather than `+00:00`.
- I would like something shorter to type, for such a basic common task.

My Question here is the same as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164826/56752), but for BSD rather than Linux (apparently).

Answer (score 5):

Since you want "Z" (GMT) you can do it simply with a format string and the literal T and Z characters

```
% TZ=GMT date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
2019-07-13T02:04:16Z
```

If you don't want to type that each time, you can make it a function or a script

eg

```
% isotime()
{
  TZ=GMT date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
}

% isotime
2019-07-13T02:06:42Z
```

Comment: Note you need to add `-u` (UTC) otherwise you get the date that seems like UTC but really is in your local timezone. So the full command would be `date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`

Comment: @wizzard0 No `-u` is needed. The zero-offset time zone is specified by setting the `TZ` variable: `TZ=GMT`. IMHO `UTC` should be used instead because the meaning of `GMT` is a little bit ambiguous.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong Yeah it should work like that, however I ran into a situation where `date` ignored `TZ` at least once, and `-u` worked flawlessly. Can't recall the exact environment right now tho :/